# How to get and set a ref for a newly cached related object in Apollo client InMemoryCache?

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have a set of related items like so:

```
book {
  id
  ...
  related_entity {
    id
    ...
  }
}
```

which apollo caches as two separate cache objects, where the `related_entity` field on `book` is a ref to an `EntityNode` object. This is fine, the related entity data is also used elsewhere outside of the context of a `book` so having it separate works, and everything seems well and good and updates as expected...except in the case where the related entity does not exist on the initial fetch (and thus the ref on the `book` object is null) and I create one later on.

I've tried adding an `update` function to the `useMutation` hook that creates the aforementioned `related_entity` per their documentation: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#example-adding-an-item-to-a-list like this:

```js
const [mutateEntity, _i] = useMutation(CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ENTITY,{
    update(cache, {data}) {
        cache.modify({
          id: `BookNode:${bookId}`,
          fields: {
            relatedEntity(_i) {
              const newEntityRef = cache.writeFragment({
                fragment: gql`
                  fragment NewEntity on EntityNode {
                    id
                    ...someOtherAttr
                  }`,
                data: data.entityData
              });
              return newEntityRef;
            }
          }
        })
    }
  });
```

but no matter what I seem to try, `newEntityRef` is always undefined, even though the new EntityNode is definitely in the cache and can be read just fine using the exact same fragment. I could give up and just force a refetch of the Book object, but the data is already *right there*.

Am I doing something wrong/is there a better way?
Barring that is there another way to get a ref for a cached object given you have its identifier?

Comment: it's explained at https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#example-updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation ? follow more strictly the example code (readField, return existing ref etc.)

Comment: The question itself already links to this exact doc and the code follows the example code _pretty_ closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is actually an issue with `apollo-cache-persist` - I removed it and the code above functions as expected per the docs. It also looks like I could instead update to the new version under a different package name `apollo3-cache-persist`, but I ended up not needing cache persistence anyway.